# generating pfx with 3DES without SHA1 as signature algo

Tags: azure, sha, pki, ejbca

I have a certificate in a `.PEM` file and a key.
The signing algorithm of the certificate file is `SHA256WithRSAEncryption`.

When I create a `.p12`/`.pfx` file using the certificate file and the key the Signature Algorithm of `.p12`/`.pfx` file changes to

```
PKCS7 Encrypted data: pbeWithSHA1And3-KeyTripleDES-CBC
```

**Is there a way I can get a SHA-2 certificate after the process**?

Answer (score 0):

The certificate is embedded within the PKCS#12 container.  Only the CA which issued the certificate can legitimately change the signature, which it can't/hasn't.

As you show in your question, the `pbeWithSHA1And3-KeyTripleDES-CBC` is for the PKCS#7 Encrypted data, which is the secure *bag* containing your unmodified SHA256WithRSAEncryption certificate.